# How much I have to wait for my question to be answered?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/66169/32188
This question I asked 16 hrs ago and no one not a single person have answered it. This is for first time the delay thats why I am asking?

Comment: You are not guaranteed an answer. You could wait indefinitely.

Comment: A bounty will help alot.

Comment: There is no guarantee of ever getting an answer. Why do you expect a guarantee at all, I wonder?

Comment: 16 hrs is not even enough to ensure that SE users around the world have had a reasonable chance to read it.

Comment: Well I stopped reading after `Its a very dumb question to me and as well as to you`. If it's a dumb question, why would I bother with it?

Comment: @ColleenV if you have not read it why are you telling me this . Thus doesn't even matter to me

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. The way that you've written your question could be turning some people away that might be able to answer it, which means it will take longer to get an answer. Well-written questions tend to get answered more quickly in my experience. If I have a question that is taking longer than I think it should to get a response, I look at it to see if I can improve it to make it more interesting or attractive.

Comment: The assertion that the question is dumb, and the implication that anyone who answers it is even dumber, is not likely to generate a huge flood of answers:(

Comment: @ColleenV thnx for yoir concern . Sorry for my reply.

Answer (score 7):

As long as it takes.

You don't get an instant answer every single time you ask a question. Just be patient and someone might be able to answer your question. In the meanwhile, you could try editing your question so you have multiple paragraphs, instead of one huge block of text. You could also, edit your question for clarity and if necessary to get attention, use a bounty.